# Scaffold-DbContext for database views in EF Core 2.1 (Query Types)

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

EF Core 2.1 has new feature - **Query Types**.

> Some of the main usage scenarios for query types are:
>
> - Serving as the return type for ad hoc FromSql() queries.
> - **Mapping to database views.**
> - Mapping to tables that do not have a primary key defined.
> - Mapping to queries defined in the model.

I upgrade project to Core 2.1, but Scaffold-DbContext still does not generate database views. I have to use a special parameter or the Scaffold-DbContext does not support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not supported in 2.1. See issue [#1679](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1679).

Comment: It should be supported in version 2.2. Here is roadmap for EF Core 2.2: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/308

Comment: it's postponed to version 3.0, see: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/308#issuecomment-432395781

Answer (score 5):

Here's a hackish but working solution:

#### How to Scaffold Controllers with database views to EF Core 2.1

1. Create view in database.
2. Create a POCO with same structure as view.
3. Add a new Controller with POCO created in step#2
   a. If key related error occurs, add a `Key` attribute on a column and then remove after scaffolding is completed.
4. A new property with `DbSet<T>` should have gotten added where `T` is the class created in step#2. Change `DbSet` to `DbQuery`.
5. In `OnModelCreating` method of `DbContext`, add following code:

   ```
   modelBuilder.Query<POCO from step#2>().ToView("Name of the view");
   ```

[Source](https://shawt.io/r/Y)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I'm very new to this, I'll make sure of it next time.

Comment: Updated with the content.