# Oracle Scaffold-DbContext for Net Core not have [Key] attribute? (.net Core v.2.1)

Tags: .net, oracle, asp.net-core

I use

```
Scaffold-DbContext "connectionSTRING" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir OracleModels -DataAnnotations -force;
```

My expect object Generate have include Attribute [KEY]

My .net core v.2.1 [LTS] and oracle currently only support for ef2.1. (not 3.1)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in core 2.1 version , it needs to be used `in core 3.0 and above`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378745/scaffold-dbcontext-for-database-views-in-ef-core-2-1-query-types).

For whether oracle supports the use of ef core 3.0 version, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/49).

Maybe you can try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280091/odp-net-core-scaffold-db-context).